# Как заполнять мета тег title на разных страницах сайта на Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

На сайте(который на wordpress) сейчас одинаковый текст написан в мета теге title - такой же, как и был изначально для главной страницы сайта. Как поменять его на других страницах(страницах статей..)?

Comment: Какой вид должен приобрести текст в теге `title`? Вы хотите выводить заголовки статей, название сайта плюс заголовок, что-то ещё?

Answer (score 1):

Заменить в шаблоне (скорее всего header.php)

```html
<title>Текущий заголовок</title>
```

На

```html
<title><?php the_title(); ?></title>
```

Comment: поменял, но теперь оно взяло левую фразу из текста в title(

Comment: Оно берет название страницы, а не левую фразу.